# How to delete everything in a string after a specific character?

Tags: linux, bash

Example:

```
before: text_before_specific_character(specific_character)text_to_be_deleted
after: text_before_specific_character
```

I know that it can be done with `sed`. But I'm stuck. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's no reason to use an external tool such as sed for this; bash can do it internally, [using parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073):

If the character you want to trim after is `:`, for instance:

```
$ str=foo_bar:baz
$ echo "${str%%:*}"
foo_bar
```

You can do this in both greedy and non-greedy ways:

```
$ str=foo_bar:baz:qux
$ echo "${str%:*}"
foo_bar:baz
$ echo "${str%%:*}"
foo_bar
```

Especially if you're calling this inside a tight loop, starting a new sed process, writing into the process, reading its output, and waiting for it to exit (to reap its PID) can be substantial overhead that doing all your processing internal to bash won't have.

---

Now -- often, when wanting to do this, what you might *really* want is to split a variable into fields, which is better done with `read`.

For instance, let's say that you're reading a line from `/etc/passwd`:

```
line=root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
IFS=: read -r name password_hashed uid gid fullname homedir shell _ <<<"$line"
echo "$name" # will emit "root"
echo "$shell" # will emit "/bin/bash"
```

---

Even if you want to process multiple lines from a file, this too can be done with bash alone and no external processes:

```
while read -r; do
  echo "${REPLY%%:*}"
done <file
```

...will emit everything up to the first `:` from each line of `file`, without requiring any external tools to be launched.

Comment: this works from right to left?  is there anything that works from left to right?  what if you dont know how many of these special characters there are?  you just want to cut the first one from left to right.

Comment: @TimBoland Just as `%` deals with suffixes, `#` deals with prefixes, so both are available. If you want to just read everything into an array, that's what `IFS=: read -r -a arrayname` is for.

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is actually really easy:

```
sed 's/A.*//'
```

Where `A` marks the specific character. Note that it is case sensitive, if you want to catch multiple characters use

```
sed 's/[aAbB].*//'
```

Answer (score 2):

If TEXT contains your text, as in

```
TEXT=beforexafter
```

and the specific character happens (for example) to be `x`, then

```
echo "${TEXT%x*}"
```

does what you want.

To Bash, `"$TEXT"` or `"${TEXT}"` is the whole `beforexafter`, but `"${TEXT%xafter}"` is just `before`, with the `xafter` chopped off the end.  To chop off the `x` and anything that might follow it, one writes `"${TEXT%x*}"`.

There is also `"${TEXT%%x*}"`, incidentally.  This differs from the other only if there is more than one `x`.  With the `%%`, Bash chops off all `x`, whereas with the `%` it chops off only from the last `x`.  You can remember this by observing loosely that the longer `%%` chops off more text.

You can do likewise with Sed, of course, if you prefer:

```
echo "$TEXT" | sed 's/x.*//'
```

Comment: Please put quotes around expansions -- `echo $TEXT` will do string-splitting, so if `TEXT` contains `$'foo\t\tbar\nbaz'`, it'll come out simply as `foo bar baz`, whereas `echo "$TEXT"` doesn't exhibit this flaw. (Perpetuating the all-caps non-environment variable thing is also a bit unfortunate; best practice is to make them lower case to avoid namespace conflicts with environment variables and builtins).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  You are right about the quotes:  omitting them is a bad habit of mine that I should reform from now.  Regarding the all-caps, you make an interesting point, with an even more interesting explanation.  I suspect that your advice regarding the caps is good.

Comment: Not the question, but related.  To get `after` run `echo "${TEXT#*x}"`