# Variables in make target depending on its directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this make target. Its intention is to rely on the output directory as well as the source. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265381/how-to-delete-everything-in-a-string-after-a-specific-character) for truncating the file name and leaving the directories its in.

```
build/%.o: src/%.cpp build/${%%/*}/
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Then the directory make target:

```
%/:
        mkdir -p $@
```

The problem is, `${%%/*}` isn't being substituted so it only ends up making the dir `build//` instead of `build/folder/folder/`.

Comment: Isn't the `${varname%%glob}` syntax a shell thing, not a GNU make thing? If so, it can't work in a pattern rule.

Comment: @Jens It is, I need to find a way to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

build/%.o:  src/%.c | $$(dir $$@)/.dirstamp
    echo $@

%/.dirstamp:
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    touch $@
```

should do it.

Please note:

- use `|`; only existence matters, not whether directory stamp is newer
- using a `.dirstamp` is more reliable

You might want to mark the `.dirstamp` as `.SECONDARY`.  Unfortunately, `gnumake` does not support wildcards so you have to enumerate them either all, or treat every target as `.SECONDARY`

Comment: You really don't need `.dirstamp`.  Just using `/.` should be enough (`$$(dir $$@)/.` and `%/.`)

Comment: You need it when `.SECONDARY` is not used.  Else, make can try to `rm build/dir` which fails  on directories.

Comment: True.  Mentioning the directory as a target anywhere in the makefile will solve that.  E.g., a new phony rule like `makedirs : somedir/. anotherdir/.` etc.