# How to generate mobile phone number with Faker

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, faker

I'm using Laravel 9 and I want to make a faker for my `users` table:

```
public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'usr_first_name' => fake()->name(),
            'usr_last_name' => fake()->name(),
            'usr_user_name' => fake()->unique()->name(),
            'usr_mobile_phone' => , // generates a unique phone number 
            'usr_password_hash' => Hash::make('123456'),
            'usr_email_address' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'usr_is_superuser' => now(),
            'usr_is_active' => 1,
            'usr_str' => Str::random(10),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
```

So as you can see for the column `usr_mobile_phone`, I need to add a unique mobile number which has 11th character length.

But I don't know what is the command for doing that in faker!

So if you know, please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: ``fake()->unique()->phoneNumber()`` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274460/faker-generating-strange-phone-numbers

Comment: Try this fake()>numerify('###-###-####'); https://fakerphp.github.io/formatters/numbers-and-strings/#numerify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Faker generating strange phone numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274460/faker-generating-strange-phone-numbers)

Comment: @OMiShah I used `'usr_mobile_phone' => fake()->unique()->phoneNumber(),` but returns **Data too long for column 'usr_mobile_phone' at row 1**

Comment: Since faker can generate longer than 11 characters for a phone number you can probably  discard characters beyond the 11th when generating the number e.g. `substr(fake()->unique()->phoneNumber(), 0, 11);`

Comment: @apokryfos, trimming the length will give you strange outputs since numbers generated by faker contain dashes, brackets and plus sign.

Comment: @japose7523, use ``fake()->unique()->e164PhoneNumber()`` to get 12 digit number with code and plus sign and then remove the plus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fake()->e164PhoneNumber()` method to get a phone number ([E164 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164)) with the plus sign and country code, *based on the app locale* which you can customise.

Now to get unique phone number we can combine the use of `unique()` method: `fake()->unique()`

This should get you unique phone number:

```
fake()->unique()->e164PhoneNumber()
```

Example output: `+14809888523, +12705838722, +13869134701`

...now as per your requirement of 11 digit length, you can replace the plus sign:

```
'usr_mobile_phone' => str_replace('+', '', fake()->unique()->e164PhoneNumber())
```

**Please note that different countries have different country code length, resulting in different phone number length output which you need to take care of yourself.**

---

Alternatively, you can use the `fake()->numerify()` method to generate dynamic format number by passing the the format to the method or by default format `###`:

```
fake()->unique()->numerfiy('##########');
```

Example output: `0733375159, 8270962398, 5125950018`

...and then join the country code:

```
'usr_mobile_phone' => '1' . fake()->unique()->numerfiy('##########')
```